# WPF : How to bind a string to Dynamic resource for a label content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, desktop-application, dynamicresource

I am new to WPf and MVVM. I have Dynamic language change functionality in my wpf application. For this functionality I have 2 Resource dictionary for each language.On Language change in UI, I am adding and removing the corresponding ResourceDictionary to the application.
With this, at a given point of time only one Resource Dictionary is available in Application resource.

As all strings are Dynamic resource, I need to now how to add a string to a dynamic resource string in xaml.

For ex: I want something like below

```
 <Label FontWeight="Medium" Content="{DynamicResouce Name} + myText"/>
```

Here "Name" is a Key available in both resource dictionary as shown below.

```
<system:String x:Key="Name">Name</system:String>
```

Now, need to know how to attach "myText" to the Name(DynamicResource) in the Label Content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply use `TextBlock` inside the `Label`

```
<Label>
   <TextBlock>
      <Run Text="Text1"/>
      <Run Text="Text2"/>
   </TextBlock>
</Label>
```